# Laravel bulk mail queue (divided by quantity and time)

Tags: laravel, laravel-queue, laravel-mail

I have a scheduling system that sends emails with the respective calendars of each system member.

My mailing list has increased significantly (more than 800 recipients), and my email provider is generating some kind of restriction, something like SMTP tarpitting.

I think I could take all these recipients and split and send them in small packages, ie, I could use `Mail::queue()`.

**The point is:**
Is there any way that I can add queued at intervals, for example 10 minutes and that always added at the end of the queue, even if there is a new mailing package.

The idea would be (I don't know if it's the best solution), take this total amount, example 800, divide by 150, which would give 5 interactions, and of these 5 interactions, send 25 emails every 10 minutes. (25 X (60/10) X 5 == 750).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can throw all mails to your queue and then configure the queue to do a specific amount at a given time (one need redis for this): https://laravel.com/docs/master/queues#rate-limiting

So, you can focus on what you are doing and less on the how you are doing it

Comment: Wow how cool, sounds like a very good idea, didn't know this feature.I'll do the reading, thank you very much

Comment: I think "maybe" I didn't understand the operation correctly. I copied the code, and made a changes, but it's basically the same code.         `Redis::throttle('email')->allow(1)->every(25)->then(function ()
        {
            \Mail::to('customer@company.com')
                ->send(new MailableOrderShipped());
        }, function() {
            return $this->release(25);
        });`. By my understanding, the every() method, would be the time interval, and allow() would be the maximum amount at a time, but what is the release method()? In this case, I wanted 1 email every 25 seconds

Comment: The `release` is for that case, that laravel cannot obtain a lock. So, when your `allow ... every` does not work, you can specify on `release` how many item should be released instead.